# jQuery mouseenter functions - changing colour if colour isn't already

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

So, I am not that fluent with jQuery and I have written a bit of code in it that doesn't look as if it works. Here is my code;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginSelector").mouseenter(function() {
        if $("#loginSelector").style.backgroundColor != "#3064CA" {
            $("#loginSelector").style.backgroundColor = "#3064CA";
        };
    });

    $("#loginSelector").mouseleave(function() {
        if $("#loginSelector").style.backgroundColor != "#5990DE" {
            $("#loginSelector").style.backgroundColor = "#5990DE";
        };
    });

    $("#signupSelector").mouseenter(function() {
        if $("#signupSelector").style.backgroundColor != "#3064CA" {
            $("#signupSelector").style.backgroundColor = "#3064CA";
        };
    });

    $("#signupSelector").mouseleave(function() {
        if $("#signupSelector").style.backgroundColor != "#5990DE" {
            $("#signupSelector").style.backgroundColor = "#5990DE";
        };
    });
});
```

All I want the code to do is check to see if the button is not a certain colour, and if it isn't that colour and it is hovered on, it changes to another colour.

Comment: What determines the colour of the buttons (CSS, conditional statements)? And why can't you just use CSS for that purpose?

Comment: Any reason you can't  use css..?

Comment: Why bother checking if it is already of a particular color?. Just apply whatever color is appropriate for each of the events, no matter if it is applied or not.

Comment: wondering whether the answers helped...

Answer (score 0):

Try this and follow the same for the rest of the blocks.

```
$("#loginSelector").mouseenter(function() { //when hovered on
    var desiredColor = "#3064CA"; //define the desired color
    if ( $(this).css('color') === desiredColor) return; //if the element's color = the desired color, don't do anything. stop the execution
    $(this).css('color', desiredColor); //else set the desired color
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the elements initially have the color `#5990DE`, I'd simply add the following css:

```
#loginSelector, #signupSelector{
 background: #5990DE;
}
#loginSelector:hover, #signupSelector:hover{
 background: #3064CA;
}
```

Or if otherwise,

css:

```
.onHover{
 background: #3064CA;
}
.onLeave{
 background: #5990DE;
}
```

script:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'loginSelector , #signupSelector', function(){
 $(this).addClass('onHover').removeClass('onLeave');
}); 
$(document).on('mouseleave', '#loginSelector , #signupSelector', function(){
 $(this).addClass('onLeave').removeClass('onHover');
});
```